# How to add basic auth in specific conf if I include location/ in a global Magento conf

Tags: nginx-config

I include a global Magento.conf using `include /etc/nginx/Magento2.conf`
so the location/ block is defined from the global conf above. Now if I want to add basic http auth... where and how do I add .htpasswd location in the site specific vhost config for Nginx.

Just adding the block would throw duplicate location/ block

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... it was easy. Never realized you can put auth directive just after the servername directive

Example

```
    server {
    listen      95.216.41.220:443 ssl http2;
    server_name devdomain.com ;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/.htpasswd;
```